# Set the database location in the connection string thought AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData

Tags: c#, wpf, connection-string

I've found out how to use the `|DataDirectory|` in the connection string to set the directory where my wpf app's database file resides, but I wish to go a little further.

As stated in the msdn [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx),

> The path may be absolute or relative by using the DataDirectory substitution string. If DataDirectory is used, the database file must exist within a subdirectory of the directory pointed to by the substitution string.

Now, i want to set the full location, not just the `DataDirectory`, with a custom `DatabaseLocation` attribute which is controlled by the application and thus I won't need to handle the connection string.

In other words, my connection string will go from this:

```
connectionString="Data Source='|DataDirectory|\database.sdf'" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0"
```

into this:

```
connectionString="Data Source='|DatabaseLocation|" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0"
```

and in the code, I'll read the user configuration and set the convenient data to the proper location:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DatabaseLocation", someVarWithDatabaseLocation);
```

This way I'll not need the content of the `someVarWithDatabaseLocation` from the user interface to the business down to the dataaccess and create a connection string.

Is this possible, or only the `|DataDirectory|` magic tag is treated by the connection string builder?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. There isn't.
After decompiling System.Data (sorry) and analysing the available ConnectionString constructors I saw that there is only ExpandDataDirectory and it has hardcoded to the

```
const string DataDirectory = "|datadirectory|";
```

So... only datadirectoy is handled...